# Type mismatch error in soapmapper

Tags: vba, soap

What could be causing the error

> Soapmapper: converting data for soapmapper failed inside the typemapper
>   HRESULT=0x80020005: type mismatch

when running the code below?

```
's is a valid XML 
xml_doc.LoadXML s

Dim Nds As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Set Nds = xml_doc.ChildNodes

Dim module As clsws_ProfileManagement
Set module = New clsws_ProfileManagement

Set Value = module.wsm_MyProcedure(Nds)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Module` is a reserved word in VBA. Try changing this in your code and see if it works.

```
's is a valid XML 
xml_doc.LoadXML s

Dim Nds As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Set Nds = xml_doc.ChildNodes

Dim modu As clsws_ProfileManagement
Set modu = New clsws_ProfileManagement

Set Value = modu.wsm_MyProcedure(Nds)
```

Comment: No, I've changed it and got same problem